# how can i write a aequivalenz relation in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

**Problem:**

aequivalenz relation in python3

**Expected result:**

```
ist_aequivalenzrelation (1 , [(1 , 1 )])  =>  True

ist_aequivalenzrelation (1 , [(2 , 2 )])  =>  False

ist_aequivalenzrelation (4 , [(1 , 1), (2 ,2 ), (3 ,3 ), (4 ,4 )])  =>  True

ist_aequivalenzrelation (3 , [(2 , 2), (1 ,1 ), (3 ,3 ), (4 ,4) , (1 , 2) , (2 , 1), (2 ,3 ), (3 ,2 )])  =>  False

ist_aequivalenzrelation (2 , [(1 , 1), (2 ,2 ), (1 ,2 ), (2 ,1) , (1 , 1) , (2 , 2 )]
```

**My solution:**

Comment: Please describe your problem in whole sentences.

Comment: This should be written in your question, edit your question and provide a little solution by yourself so we could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CoMa at the TU Berlin? It's the task for this week, there.

Basically you should write something like this:

```
def ist_aequivalenzrelation(n,R):
      for i in range(1,n+1):
          if (i,i) not in R:
              return False
          for j in range(1,n+1):
              if (i,j) in R and (j,i) not in R:
                    return False
              for k in range(1,n+1):
                   if (i,j) and (j,k) and not (i,k) in R:
                      return False
       return True
```

which checks reflexivity,symmetrie and transitivity (this order above). This code, tho will be way too slow to be accepted by the judge^^.
Good luck